# BorderPane center overlap other parts

Tags: javafx

When I use BorderPane and put a layout in the center part , it covers other parts , how can I prevent the center part of covering other parts n borderPane 
[image]

as you see , the table covers the right part of the BorderPane .
I put the table inside Pane .

Comment: Care to share the overall structure of the scene graph with us? Are there any transformations applied? Are any min sizes set that do not allow the scene to be layouted properly given the scene size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) documentation:

> BorderPane does not clip its content by default, so it is possible that childrens' bounds may extend outside its own bounds if a child's min size prevents it from being fit within it space.

To prevent overflow, some options are:

1. You could code your child node so that it does not have a min size.
2. You can ensure that the sum of min sizes of all children is at least equal to the min size of the border pane.
3. You can explicitly set a [clip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) on your child node.  For a demo, see: [JavaFX Pane Clipping](http://news.kynosarges.org/2016/11/03/javafx-pane-clipping/).

   ```
   final Rectangle outputClip = new Rectangle();
   childNode.setClip(outputClip);

   childNode.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
       outputClip.setWidth(newValue.getWidth());
       outputClip.setHeight(newValue.getHeight());
   });
   ```
4. The order you set child nodes into the border pane determines which is displayed on top, so if all the nodes are opaque, you could set the center pane first and the sides panes will be painted over any overflow.

Comment: 1-You could code your child node so that it does not have a min size.
it works , thank you :)